# How to retrieve public key from attestationObject in java

Tags: webauthn

I am getting attestationObject: ArrayBuffer(648) from registartion process.
I want to fetch the public key from attestationObject.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a trivial topic. I'd suggest looking at existing implementations and either using them if you can or at least look at their code to see how they've done it.

A Java one:
https://github.com/webauthn4j/webauthn4j

A .Net one:
https://github.com/abergs/fido2-net-lib

Spec:
https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#attestation-object

Answer (score 1):

Here is the structure[image]

Suggest reading my article on verifying FIDO2 responses https://herrjemand.medium.com/verifying-fido2-responses-4691288c8770